# Adding a random key from a dictionary to a list in python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.3

I'm struggling to figure out what's wrong with my code. I am trying to randomly select a key from several dictionaries, then add that key to the beginning of a list. For example:

```
import random
list1 = ["list"]
dict1 = {"key1" : "def1", "key2" : "def2", "key3" : "def3"}
dict2 = {"key4" : "def4", "key5" : "def5", "key6" : "def6"}
DICTIONARIES = [dict1, dict2]
value = random.choice(DICTIONARIES)
key = random.choice(list(value.keys()))
list1[:0] = key
print (list1)
```

What I want, is a print result of [key5, list]. What I get is ['k', 'e', 'y', '5', list]

Any ideas? is there a better way to search multiple dictionaries for a random key that will produce the desired results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that `item` variable is the same as `list1`. If yes, try this:

```
list1[:0] = [key]
```

Or, alternatively you may use the `list.insert` function instead of slice assignment:

```
list1.insert(0, key)
```

Your version was working like the following:

- Before assignment: `list1 = ['list']`, `key = 'key5'`
- Left side of assignment refers to element before `'list'` in `list1`
- Right side refers to value of `key`, which is `"key5"`.
- `"key5"` is a sequence of `k`, `e`, `y` and `5`.
- So, by `list1[:0] = key` we concatenate `"key5"` *sequence* and `list1`.
- But in `list1[:0] = [key]` we concatenate `[key]` sequence (that has only one element that equals to "key5") and `list1`. And that's what we actually want.

Comment: Yes item was supposed to be list1. Sorry, working on too much stuff and got mixed up :-) Your explaination was very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
import random
list1 = ["list"]
dict1 = {"key1" : "def1", "key2" : "def2", "key3" : "def3"}
dict2 = {"key4" : "def4", "key5" : "def5", "key6" : "def6"}

all_keys = list(dict1.keys() | dict2.keys())  #creates a list containing all keys
key = random.choice(all_keys)
list1.insert(0,key) 
print (list1)          #prints  ['key1', 'list']
```

Comment: In Python 3 one should use `print()` syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will use this method in future.

Answer (score 1):

In Python `string` objects are iterable, so, this line

```
list1[:0] = key
```

and this

```
list1[:0] = list(key)
```

are equals, and means *replace all elements from 0th position to 0th position in `list1` with elements from `key`*. You should use `insert` function, or make a list with `key` element and assign it.